# Merging multiple nodes in XSLT version 1.0 or 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Condition to merge --> Below are condition to merge sample xml

```
 1. Merge multiple nodes based on Operations and 
 2. Attribute with value as
```

/*:Request/*:Attribute[*:Name='ID']/*:Value/*:NewValue**

```
 Input XML message-->
    
   <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<tns:Requests xmlns:tns="http://sample.com/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sample.com/v1">
   <?audit suppress oracle.ide.xml.validation-error?>
   <tns:Request>
      <tns:System>ABC</tns:System>
      <tns:Operation>Modify</tns:Operation>
      <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>ID</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
            <tns:NewValue>999</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
      </tns:Attribute>
      <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>TITLE</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
              <tns:NewValue>Manager</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
      </tns:Attribute>
   </tns:Request>
   <tns:Request>
      <tns:System>ABC</tns:System>
      <tns:Operation>Modify</tns:Operation>
      <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>ID</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
            <tns:NewValue>999</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
      </tns:Attribute>
      <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>COUNTRY</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
            <tns:NewValue>Ghana</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
      </tns:Attribute>
   </tns:Request>
   <tns:Request>
      <tns:System>ABC</tns:System>
      <tns:Operation>Disable</tns:Operation>
      <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>ID</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
            <tns:NewValue>888</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
      </tns:Attribute>
      <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>STATUS</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
            <tns:NewValue>Inactive</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
      </tns:Attribute>
   </tns:Request>
</tns:Requests>
```

3. Need to use XSLT to transform input xml message to expected output

   ```
   **Expected Output**

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <tns:Requests xmlns:tns="http://sample.com/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sample.com/v1">
     <?audit suppress oracle.ide.xml.validation-error?>
     <tns:Request>
       <tns:System>ABC</tns:System>
       <tns:Operation>Modify</tns:Operation>
       <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>ID</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
           <tns:NewValue>999</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
       </tns:Attribute>
       <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>TITLE</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
           <tns:NewValue>Manager</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
       </tns:Attribute>
       <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>COUNTRY</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
           <tns:NewValue>USA</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
       </tns:Attribute>
     </tns:Request>
     <tns:Request>
       <tns:System>ABC</tns:System>
       <tns:Operation>Disable</tns:Operation>
       <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>ID</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
           <tns:NewValue>888</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
       </tns:Attribute>
       <tns:Attribute>
         <tns:Name>STATUS</tns:Name>
         <tns:Value>
           <tns:NewValue>Inactive</tns:NewValue>
         </tns:Value>
       </tns:Attribute>
     </tns:Request>
   </tns:Requests>
   ```
4. Not able to merge multiple nodes as explain in output section using xslt based on multiple attribute
5. How to group based on Attribute

   Code

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!-- current-grouping-key.xsl -->
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="Requests">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|* except Request"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Request" group-by="Operation">
            <Request>
              <System>ABC</System>
              <Operation>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
              </Operation>
             <xsl:for-each-group select="Attribute" group-by="NewValue">
                 <Attribute>
             <Name>ID</Name>
             <Value>
                <NewValue>  <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></NewValue>
             </Value>
          </Attribute>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
         <Attribute>
            <Name> <xsl:value-of select="Name"/></Name>
             <Value>
                <NewValue><Name> <xsl:value-of select="NewValue"/></Name></NewValue>
             </Value>
          </Attribute>
          </xsl:for-each> 
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </Request>

          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: thank you @michael.hor257k, I have updated the code, but it is now showing desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://sample.com/v1">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Requests">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|* except Request"/>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="Request" group-by="Operation">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="System, Operation"/>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/Attribute" group-by="Value/NewValue">
              <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Name, Value"/>
              </xsl:copy>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```